# how do i insert a string into an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, scanf

So basically I have something like this:

```
char string[256]; 
printf("Insert text:");
```

and i want to read (scanf) the text into the array, how would I accomplish this.

Comment: It's such a basic thing that every book or tutorial should have told you that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put some text in `string` variable you can use:

1) `fgets()` -> `fgets(string,256,stdin);`

2) `scanf()` -> `scanf(" %255s",string);`

By using `fgets`, one can input a string which contains space.

However by using `scanf` one cannot input a string which contains space.

---

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char string[256]; 
    char *p;
    printf("Insert text:");
    fgets(string,256,stdin);
    //Remove \n from string
    if ((p=strchr(string, '\n')) != NULL)
        *p = '\0';
    printf("The string using fgets: %s\n",string);
    printf("Insert text again:");
    scanf(" %255s",string);
    printf("The string using scanf: %s\n",string);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Insert text:hello world
The string using fgets: hello world
Insert text again:hello world
The string using scanf: hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scanf("%s", string);
```

or more correctly..

```
scanf("%255s", string);
```

%s will read a string, the 255 limits the string length to 255 chars, leaving at least one space for the null string terminator.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished simply by using either

1. scanf () or
2. gets()

functions

see the following program which uses scanf() to read two string

http://www.csnotes32.com/2014/08/c-function-to-compare-two-strings.html